# Mean Value Theorem analogue for several variables.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The statement of MVT is as follows:

$f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function.Then for $x\in (a,b)$ we have,

$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x+\theta h).h$,$(0<\theta<1)$ if $x+h\in (a,b)$

Now consider a function $f:U\to \mathbb R$ of $n$ variables,$U$ being open set,then MVT should be,

Let $U$ be an open convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$.
Let $f:U\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable.Then for $x,y\in U$ we have,

$f(\mathbf{x+h})-f(\mathbf x)=\nabla f(\mathbf x+\theta\mathbf h).\mathbf h$ for some $0<\theta<1$

I want an example where this theorem fails if we drop the assumption that $U$ is convex.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables

Comment: Can someone give me a counterexample in the case $U$ is not convex.

Comment: Convexity is not the important thing. If $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ is open and $\gamma:[0,1]\to U$ is a differentiable curve, then $f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))=(f\circ \gamma)'(\theta)=(\nabla f)(\gamma(\theta))\cdot \gamma'(\theta)$ for some $0<\theta<1$. In the special case where $\gamma$ is a straight line, you recover the formula you wrote (and of course, since $U$ is open, if you fix an $x$, then all nearby points can be joined to $x$ by a straight line).